# React Bug In Displaying Element With The Same Key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I accidentally wrote some bad codes today and I would like to know why React shows me that result.

My code is something like this:

```
class Prova extends React.Component {
  
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      people : [],
      counter : 0,
      person : {
        name: "Michele",
        surname: "Scavino"
      } 
   }
}
  
  addPeople = () => {
    this.state.person["id"] = this.state.counter;
    this.state.people = [
      ...this.state.people,
      this.state.person
    ];

    this.setState({counter: this.state.counter + 1});
  }

  render() {     
    return (
      <div>
        {
          this.state.people?.map(el => {
            return (
              <div key={el.id}>
                {el.name}
                {el.surname}
                {el.id}
              </div>
            )
          })
        }    
       <br />
       <br />
       <br />
       <br />
       <button onClick={this.addPeople}>Add person</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Prova />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

The error here is that whenever I add a new person with the apposite button I copy the same ref of the same object in the array and when I go to change the ID of an element of the array, all of the ID of the elements of the array will change, using the spread operatore in this way.
But the problem here is another. Whenever I add a new person also the displaying of new elements is very strange and I can't undestand why. If I click the button six times it should display to me  6 rows but actually it doesn't happen. It litterally freakout!!!
I know that I'm trying to display a list of elements with the same keys but I can't realize why this trouble happen...
Is there any expert who can answer my question appropiately or link me some resources to find out the answer to my question?
I really suggest you to copy and run my code to see the bug with you eyes.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an incremental id from within your component since it will be changed along with every render, Reactjs still miss your last rendering Id.

You will need to have a consistent id during renders:

One very popular solution is to use this UUID generator: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: Thanks you man, you said what I need. So if I change the key of the elements when react has already render them, it gets confused!? And it pop up randomly components on my screen...

Comment: Absolutely correct! The render listing needs to be consistent with every render. If you change it in each render, React will dislocate your element.

Comment: One side note is that you should not mutate state directly and use setState(). here: this.state.person["id"] = this.state.counter; and here: this.state.people.

Comment: You are welcome, mate! We raise by lifting others.

Answer (score 0):

key in a map must be unique. You can use `id` to set a key:

```
{
  this.state.people?.map((el) => {
    return (
      <div key={el.id}>
        {el.name}
        {el.surname}
        {el.id}
      </div>
    );
  });
}
```

And update addPeople like this:

```
addPeople = () => {
  this.state.people = [...this.state.people, { ...this.state.person, id: this.state.counter }];

  this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
};
```

Comment: every item in the array has the same id. I said the code is bad, I copy the same object every single time...
I want to know why react work in this way with a list of elements to display with the same key

Comment: Yeah, I already know the solution... What i asked for is why React behave like that. Why if I click the button addPerson and making all of the id of the components already displayed change React freakout displaying a random number of components...